# Orchard CMS Packaging Theme/Module Fail - Cannot create a package that has no dependencies nor content

Tags: orchardcms, packaging, orchardcms-1.7, orchardcms-1.8

Orchard 1.8. While I can package the default theme successfully (TheThemeMachine) Using the command line instructions from [here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Using-the-command-line-interface) E.g 
    orchard> package create TheThemeMachine C:\Temp

packaging my own themes I get the following error 
**"Cannot create a package that has no dependencies nor content."**
(the theme indeed has content)
Anybody have the same issue ? Rookie error I'm guessing..But help much appreciated as error appears undocumented.

Comment: @Xeevis currently unable to replicate issue...

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you have set wrong version for the module/theme. For NuGet it's important to have correct versioning. Make sure you have version in your **Theme.txt** following formats {x.x}, {x.x.x}, {x.x.x.x} (where x are only digits, each up to 10)

### Valid:

```
1.0  
0.0.0.1  
01.4423.455.112312
1234567890.1234567890.1234567890.1234567890
```

### Invalid:

```
1  
.1  
1.1.1.1.1
1.12345678901
```